# How can I clone a non-github hosted repository using Github Desktop

Tags: git, github, gogs

How can I clone a non-github repository using [Github Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/)?

`https://local-git-service/some-user/some-repo.git`

If I have an existing repository initialized, I can add it using Github Desktop.  But how can I clone it without using the git command?

Our team uses an internal [Gogs](http://gogs.io/) site to manage our repositories, and we would like to allow users to clone the repository without using command line tools.

Answer (score 3):

### For Mac

[Github Desktop](https://desktop.github.com) understands the github-mac://openRepo URL format/protocol.

For instance: `github-mac://openRepo/http://somegitservice.local/some-user/my-repo`

If you enter a link with that format into your browser's address bar, it should prompt you to open it with Github Desktop.  This will not work if you do not have Github Desktop installed.

### For Windows

I'm not sure!  Until Github provides a similar solution, command line or another tool must be used to clone the repository to your Desktop.  Once it's cloned to your desktop you can add it to Github Desktop using the `+` > `Add` button in the top-left of the window.

Answer (score 3):

**Clone repository**

1. Create a repository (don't need to follow remote name, use any name).
2. Add remote to the repository settings. (Mac: Repository > Repository Settings; Win: "Gear icon" > "Repository Settings" > "Remote"; **USE HTTP/HTTPS ADDRESS**. Because SSH authentication requires you use command line for once. I mentioned in the third part of this answer.)
3. Permanently **delete** the repository folder!
4. (For Mac GitHub Desktop only) Click `Publish` once on the upper-right corner. This will not change the remote repository at all **FOR NOW**. This behavior may change in the later release of GitHub Desktop. This step is crucial because otherwise, you won't be able to see the `Clone Again` option in step 5. But Windows users do not need to do this.
5. Go back to GitHub Desktop, Click `Clone Again`. It will prompt you to type login information.
6. That's it. Enjoy Git, GitHub Desktop, Gogs!

(**Please make sure you type the login information CORRECTLY if you want to click `remember password`** so that you don't need to type it again and again. Because I happened to type it wrongly on Mac for the second test, and I have not found a place to change that. So I guess I need to re-install GitHub Desktop to correct it. I may be also going to write to GitHub for an answer. Will update this section if I get an answer. But as long as you type it correctly, it works perfectly.)

---

**Tested on**

Mac OS 10.10; GitHub Desktop, Deer Types (222), Latest version as of writing.

Win 10 Enterprise; GitHub Desktop, Chocolate-Covered Yaks (3.3.3.0) bc4735a, Latest version as of writing.

---

This step is for people who would like to use SSH connection. Requires the usage of command line, but it's once for all. (This step is what I think one must do if s/he is going to use SSH connection.)

**Add SSH Key**

**For Mac:**

Open GitHub Desktop, Press `Command+T` ( Or click "Repository>Open in Terminal")

Type: `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` and press `enter`

Copy paste the output to your Gogs SSH Keys List.

One may have a different name for `id_rsa.pub`. (Seems there is an order for the keys that GitHub Desktop use to connect to remote server. I tried to use github's public key, failed. I didn't spend much time to figure out it. Just use `id_rsa.pub`.)

**For Win:**

Pretty much the same. But open the terminal by `clicking the "Gear icon" on the top-right corner` > `open in Git Shell`. Copy paste the `~/.ssh/github_rsa.pub` file content instead.

Comment: We're looking for a solution that doesn't use CLI, but this seems like it has very limited command line, so I'll upvote :)

Comment: @JohnathanElmore If users use HTTP/HTTPS connect, then no command line is required. I changed the order of my answer so that it goes with the non-command line first.

Answer (score 1):

According to Github guides, Github Desktop provides only adding local repositories, see [Adding a repository from your local computer to GitHub Desktop](https://help.github.com/desktop/guides/contributing/adding-a-repository-from-your-local-computer-to-github-desktop/)

On the other hand, older Github for Windows can be used with non-Github repositories, according to [Haacked.com - Using Github for Windows with non-Github repositories](http://haacked.com/archive/2012/05/30/using-github-for-windows-with-non-github-repositories.aspx/) . You could test the suggested drag and drop method on Github Desktop too.

Comment: The question is how to clone a repository hosted somewhere other than github.